# ErrorException: Warning: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in /../../

Tags: symfony

I am trying to create my own authentication provider like in http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html.

But, it keeps saying:

ErrorException: Warning: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in /../../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/NativeFileSessionHandler.php line 56

Comment: I have the same random error with my custom PHP session handler... No idea what it could be.

Answer (score 7):

Symfony2 sessions will not work properly with "session auto start" enabled. So make sure that's disabled.

Make sure your php configuration `php.ini` has this configured: `session.auto_start = 0`.

Or you can add `php_flag session.auto_start 0` to your `.htaccess` file if you can not edit the php.ini file.

Comment: Why in php.ini is equal 0 and in htacess is equal 1 :$ ? I have this error but doesn't work trying this solution. Merci!

Comment: Typo on my part. Corrected my answer.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, Tried this solution in CI4 and its working.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, there's one more possibility to get this error, as I found out after a long time of struggling:

For whatever reason, this crucial part was commented out in my `config_test.yml`, giving me exactly the same error:

```yaml
framework:
    session:
        storage_id: session.storage.mock_file
```

The `storage_id` setting must be in place to avoid the problem.