# "Warning: ini_set(): A session is active" error

Tags: php, session, heroku

I am making a page with a login user database using Heroku and SQL. I am having trouble translating this from PHP and MYSQL. As part of the transition, I keep getting this error on top of every page in my website, but I can't for the life of me figure out why or how to get rid of it:

Warning: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in /app/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/NativeFileSessionHandler.php on line 56

I tried reading this but didn't get anywhere:
[ErrorException: Warning: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in /../../](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539269/errorexception-warning-ini-set-a-session-is-active-you-cannot-change-the-s)

Here is the login page section of my page:

```
$app->post('/login/', function() use($app)  {

    // configuration
    //require("../includes/config.php");
$usernameExists = false;
$emailExists = false ; 

$username = $app['request']->get('username');
$password = $app['request']->get('password');

$st = $app['pdo']->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where username = ?") ;
$st -> execute(array($username));
$userinfo = array() ; 
 while ($row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $app['monolog']->addDebug('Row ' . $row['username']);
    $userinfo[] = $row;
  }   

if (count($userinfo) == 1  )
{
     $row = $userinfo[0];
     $salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64) ; 
     if (crypt($password, $salt) == crypt($row['password'], $salt))
     {
        //set session id
        session_start();
        $app['session']->set('user', array('username' => $username));
           return $app->render('myshows.php'/*, array(
    'names' => $usernames ) */
      );
     }
     else 
     {
        return $app['twig']->render('login_form.twig', array('incorrectlogin' => 1 ));
     }
}

if ($userinfo == null )
{
return $app['twig']->render('login_form.twig' , array(
    'incorrectlogin' => 1 ));
}
}) ;
```

And this is my current php.ini file:

```
; php options
date.timezone = UTC
 session.auto_start = 0
; hhvm specific 
hhvm.log.level = Warning
hhvm.log.always_log_unhandled_exceptions = true
hhvm.log.runtime_error_reporting_level = 8191
hhvm.mysql.typed_results = false
```

Comment: Make sure that `session.auto_start` is disabled.

Comment: BTW: no needs for `session_start();`. Symfony2 start the session by itself.

Comment: I added my php.ini file, saved in: \vendor\heroku\heroku-buildpack-php\conf\hhvm

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer!  I had accidentally included session_start(); in my config file. All better now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this line in cofig file

`session_start();` //need to call PHP's session object to access it though it
When you load session library it's constructor does these for you.