# Clear cache for prod. env. in Orocommerce

Tags: symfony, caching, yaml, clear-cache, orocommerce

I am trying to make changes to my `.yml` files during the run time and the `php bin/console cache:clear` command must be executed so these changes can affect the application.

I tried running the `cache:clear` command with the Controller during the run time, but I got the same error every time in different methods.

Error:

> "warning: ini_set (): A session is active. You cannot change the
> session module's ini settings at this time at
> NativeFileSessionHandler.php"

I am aware that executing the `cache:clear` command during the run time is not a good method as seen in the error, so are there any other ways to execute this command programmatically or to see the effect of changes in `.yml` files during the execution of the application without using console?

Answer (score 0):

This error is discussed here: [ErrorException: Warning: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in /../../](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539269/errorexception-warning-ini-set-a-session-is-active-you-cannot-change-the-s)

Possible sollution would be to:

> Make sure your php configuration php.ini has this configured: session.auto_start = 0.

When clearing cache for prod environment you must specify the environment since dev is the default. use --env parameter like so:

`php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: Thanks a lot for paying attention but I've tried everything you mentioned. Thanks again!